# Battery starts discharging after charge

Tags: battery, dell-mini-9

In Ubuntu 10.10 and 11.04 my Dell mini 9 starts to discharge and run off of battery very soon after it is fully charged while it's still plugged into the the power adapter. If I restart it still doesn't see the AC adapter. If I shutdown and cold boot it will start charging again until the battery is full and the circle begins a new.  It started happening at some point with 10.10 and I just now am getting around to doing something about it.

The mini 9 is running it's latest BIOS A07.  I opened the thing up to check for loose charger connections and everything looks good.  Is there a different power management driver I can try? Is there a power management log I can check somewhere?

EDIT: What libraries do I roll back and lock to 10.04 or up to 11.10? I'd like to keep with 11.04 if possible until 11.10 is officially released.

Comment: I'm not clear - have you upgraded to 11.10 - or are you asking how to go back to a previous release?  The only way to go backwards is to do a fresh install.

Answer (score 1):

It might have something to do with the (nearly) fixed power regressions in the linux kernel. I'd suggest (for laptops that is) to go back to 10.04 or go to 11.10 --> http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/  if you are spunky enough to try an alpha. If you want to get both though, you can double/triple boot (triple if you left Wins on your dell). Hope that helps!